# How to read text value through selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to crawling DigiKey Value of electronic component.

I can access the Supplier Info. using selenium & python.
But I can't read the text "Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc.".

Please help me.

[image]
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/alpha-omega-semiconductor-inc/AOD4180/2353884?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIIHkAiAWAjADgAwgLoF8g

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = '/Users/username/Django/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-search-text")
input_box.send_keys('AOD4180')
driver.find_element_by_id("header-search-button").click()

table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='MuiTableBody-root']")[0]
print(table)

trs = table.find_elements_by_xpath("tr")
print(len(trs), type(trs), dir(trs))

tr = table.find_elements_by_xpath("tr")[3]
print(type(tr), dir(tr))
```

Comment: When ever your xpathing from an element use the ./tr like so to get it from the table and not from the root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you find elements with an "s", you are finding more than one selenium webdriver element objects. When you find an element without an "s", you are finding one selenium webdriver element objects. Each one has an `element.text` attribute that converts those objects into text.

Try this.

```
trs = [i.text for i in table.find_elements_by_xpath("tr")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.
I confused attribute and function.
I tried i.text(), so I failed

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text` to get text from element.

But inside every `tr` you shold find all `td` and get text from second `td`. It is better to use relative path - starting with `./` - to search only inside selected `tr`. Without `./` it will always search from root and it may always get the same element.

BTW: if you need only first `table` then you can use `find_element_...` without char `s` in word `element` - and then you don't need `[0]`

```
from selenium import webdriver

#chromedriver = '/Users/username/Django/chromedriver'
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.digikey.com/en/products/')

input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("product-search-text")
input_box.send_keys('AOD4180')
driver.find_element_by_id("header-search-button").click()

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='MuiTableBody-root']")
#print(table)

trs = table.find_elements_by_xpath("./tr")
for row in trs:
    print('row: >>>', row.text, '<<<')
    for item in row.find_elements_by_xpath("./td"):
        print('  item.text:', item.text)

print('---')

item = trs[3].find_elements_by_xpath("./td")[1]
print('item.text:', item.text)
```

Result:

```
row: >>> Digi-Key Part Number
785-1219-2-ND - Tape & Reel (TR)
785-1219-1-ND - Cut Tape (CT)
785-1219-6-ND - Digi-Reel® <<<
  item.text: Digi-Key Part Number
  item.text: 785-1219-2-ND - Tape & Reel (TR)
785-1219-1-ND - Cut Tape (CT)
785-1219-6-ND - Digi-Reel®
  item.text: 
row: >>> Manufacturer
Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc. <<<
  item.text: Manufacturer
  item.text: Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc.
  item.text: 
row: >>> Manufacturer Product Number
AOD4180 <<<
  item.text: Manufacturer Product Number
  item.text: AOD4180
  item.text: 
row: >>> Supplier
Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc. <<<
  item.text: Supplier
  item.text: Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc.
  item.text: 
row: >>> Description
MOSFET N-CH 80V 10A/54A TO252 <<<
  item.text: Description
  item.text: MOSFET N-CH 80V 10A/54A TO252
  item.text: 
row: >>> Detailed Description
N-Channel 10A (Ta), 54A (Tc) 3.1W (Ta), 150W (Tc) Surface Mount TO-252, (D-Pak) <<<
  item.text: Detailed Description
  item.text: N-Channel 10A (Ta), 54A (Tc) 3.1W (Ta), 150W (Tc) Surface Mount TO-252, (D-Pak)
  item.text: 
row: >>> Customer Reference <<<
  item.text: Customer Reference
  item.text: 
---
item.text: Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc.
```